# rundeck - could I sftp files from desktop to various nodes?

Tags: shell, rundeck

I'm new to rundeck and understood that I can run same repetitive jobs on various nodes. But I need to sftp some files to all the nodes, how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap your nodes to rundeck against a project
After that in the project nodes section you will see these nodes
Make sure you are able to telnet to those nodes at port 22
Now create a job to sftp files from your rundeck nodes to all nodes using inline script.